# How To Distribute Visual Studio Shared Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamics-crm

I live in the Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement (aka CRM) world, where I can't have any references to any dlls that are a part of the SDK or .net.  I've been using ILMerge (actually [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack) the open source, faster/smaller version), to merge multiple dlls into a single dll that get's deployed to the online sandbox environment.  I want to get away from it for 3 reasons

1. The head of the MS SDK team says it's not supported.
2. ILMerging has to be doing some sick voodoo that scares me...
3. ILMerging increases build times.

Shared Projects work great, but as a Consultant, I don't have a good way of sharing Shared Projects among clients.  Basically I want a Nuget sort of manager for shared projects where I can search for, download, and update shared projects.  I've looked at using NuGet Source only packages, but you can't install NuGet packages into a Shared Project.

Anyone have any other ideas, options, or hacks you've done that would be helpful for sharing Shared Projects?

Comment: So why creating source only nuget package from code of your shared project does not suite your needs?

Comment: @Evk, I ran into issues going down that path, but I can't recall them all at the moment, but one example is Source only NuGet Files only get added to a project on install, not on update.  So if I add a reference to my project, and check it into Source Control, and someone else get's latest, it will not copy over the files from NuGet Package into the project.